# Updating row column value not working with sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview

So I have a table that has three columns `[ id | name | badgeID ]` .

I display the data with a recyclerview and everything works fine. I wanted to add the possibility to update the name when user click edit button for a certain item in the list and it worked perfectly. Now I want the user to edit their `badgeID` as well.

I used the same logic and code as name updating but it's NOT working ! I printed in the log the database rows with their values once I edit, and it shows the new edited name, but shows the same badgeID ?!

---

**DBHelper Class**

```
    // with this I edit the name and works fine!
    public boolean updateName(long rowId, String newName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(COLUMN_ID, rowId);
        args.put(COLUMN_NAME, newName);

        return db.update(TABLE_WORK_APP, args, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    // this for editing the badgeID and It doesn't works :(
    public boolean updateBadgeID(long rowId, int badgeId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(COLUMN_ID, rowId);
        args.put(COLUMN_BADGE_ID, badgeId);

        return db.update(TABLE_WORK_APP, args, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
```

**Activity Class**

```
   // works fine;
  public void updateName(String nameNew, int position) {
    db.updateQuote(dbList.get(position).get_id(), nameNew);
    dbList.clear();
    dbList.addAll(db.getDataFromDB());
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Name updated.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  // not working!
 public void updateBadgeID(int badgeIdNew, int position) {
    db.updateBadgeID(dbList.get(position).get_id(), badgeIdNew);
    dbList.clear();
    dbList.addAll(db.getDataFromDB());
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "badgeID updated.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Comment: How are you calling your `Activity`version of `updateBadgeID(int, int)`?

Comment: You can do this instead

    `db.execSQL("UPDATE "+ TABLE_WORK_APP + " SET "+ 
               COLUMN_BADGE_ID + "='" + badgeId + "' WHERE " +
               COLUMN_ID + "='" + rowId + "'");`

Comment: @ninetwozero what do you mean? the flow in my app is that once the user click the edit badge button a dialog show and inside the `OnPositive` callback I call the method there after the get the id the user added!? I did the same thing in edit Name and works fine.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal didn't work either? this is really weird!